# Passing a float property as an parameter

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I’m trying to set up a call to ease a portion of my program

I try to call the method below by saying...  [self aMethodToTry:self.units :row :self.unitsFloat];

```
- (void)aMethodToTry:(UITextField *)unitsRow : (int)row  : (float)units {


if (row == 1) {

    [unitsRow setText:(NSString *)[self.unitsArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    NSLog(@"This is the row -----> %ld",(long)row);
    self.unitConversionValue = [[self.unitsValueArray objectAtIndex:row]floatValue];
   // NSLog(@"%f",self.unitConversionValue);

    units = 8;
    NSLog(@"self.units float = %f", self.unitsFloat);
    NSLog(@"units = %f", units);
```

It continues on from here.. but what I want is for the passed info.. the row which is this case would be 1 to solve true for the first if and then for “self.units” to be plopped into the “unitsRow” and for self.unitsFloat to be plopped in for “units”

But when this is called .. the set text portion works fine.. however the first log shows 0. while the second shows 8.0.

is this something that can’t be done.. I just don’t see what I’m screwing up..

Why isn't it setting self.unitsFloat to 8?

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Brian

Answer (score 1):

You are in deep need of understanding basics of `Objective C` first. Take a look at this

[image: ObjC method declaration]

```
- (void) aMethodToTry:(UITextField *)unitsRow  withRow:(int)row  andUnits:(float)units {}
```

You can call this method as follows:

```
[self aMethodToTry:textField withRow:1 andUnits:23.4f];
```

Comment: It is actually allowed to write methods with "unlabelled arguments". It is not recommended at all, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Method parameters are passed *by value* (not *by reference*). That means that setting

```
 units = 8;
```

inside the method modifies the local variable `units` of the method, but it does
 *not modify* the passed argument `self.unitsFloat`.

The "text portion works fine" because `unitsRow` is a *pointer* to an Objective-C object,
and

```
[unitsRow setText:(NSString *)[self.unitsArray objectAtIndex:row]];
```

sends a message to that object. It does not modify the `unitsRow` variable.

---

To modify a float variable from within the method, you would have to pass the
address of the variable:

```
- (void)aMethodToTry:(UITextField *)unitsRow : (int)row  : (float *)unitsPtr {
    // ...
    *unitsPtr = 8.0;
}
```

But you cannot take the address of a property, therefore you would have to call this
like

```
float tmpUnits = self.unitsFloat;
[self aMethodToTry:self.units :row :&tmpUnits];
self.unitsFloat = tmpUnits;
```

Alternatively, you could set

```
self.unitsFloat = 8.0;
```

from within the method, instead of passing the property value as a parameter.

---

(And you should definitely think about using "labelled method parameters" to make
the code more readable, as demonstrated in the other answer.)